How do I aggregate data the data to build a model? I am afraid of calculating average of averages

I’m working with a raw dataset and need guidance on how to aggregate the data in order to build a model that predicts the value of column "P" (EPC).
The dataset contains 10 variables (Var1 to Var10) for about 30 records, representing a marketing funnel. Out of the 30 customers, only 12 move to the next stage in the funnel (column "M"), and eventually, just 2 of these 12 customers convert, generating revenue, which is captured in columns "N" and "O".
My concern is around data aggregation before building the model. I want to avoid the issue of the model calculating an "average of averages," which wouldn’t be accurate. Should I assign weights to the aggregated records, or is there another approach? I need the model to dynamically calculate EPC as it identifies the best combination of variables to predict EPC.
Ultimately, my goal is to find segments that exhibit significantly higher EPC. How would you recommend I proceed with this?
